# Authenticating an API call from Laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel, oauth

I'm new to using API's and am currently trying to use the Trade Me API on a new application I am developing.

Their [authorisation guidelines](http://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-overview/authorisation/) say they use OAuth to authenticate the API calls and that these can either be specified in the query string or the authorization header.

Being fairly new to API calls, I tried using the `guzzlehttp/oauth-subscriber` but failed miserably when trying to make the call.

So currently I am just trying to append the details to the query string.

The call I am trying to make requires:

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_signature
- oauth_signature_method

Where `oauth_consumer_key` is the consumer key and `oauth_signature` is the consumer secret.

When I try to visit this URL to test the URL is correct - https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/Listings/123.json?oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_signature=XXX&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT

I get an error that:

> "ErrorDescription":"Invalid PLAINTEXT signature."

I've obviously replaced my keys in the above URL but I can't see what is wrong with the above, it seems to match their documentation.

Can someone either point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you append the signature with an ampersand? It's easier if you send the authorization via the `Authorization` header. Try manually doing it via curl: `curl https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/Listings/123.json -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<consumer-key>", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_signature="<consumer-secret>&"'`. You could also try adding `&amp;` after your signature.

Comment: @Dencker OK, I'll try with `curl` later. I mean if I can figure out how to send the authorisation in a header or if someone can help me do that then I would prefer to do that. But I couldn't quite wrap my head around how to do this through Laravel. Which is why I was looking for a solution using a query string.

Comment: Which library do you use for making requests? Most of them, like Guzzle or Requests, provide a simple `->addHeader("Authorization", 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<consumer-key>".....')` method or something in that flavor.

Comment: @Dencker I was using `Guzzle`. Are you able to do this with just the basic `Guzzle` library - https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle or do you need to use something special like https://github.com/guzzle/oauth-subscriber

Comment: With the call you're making there, you should be able to use Guzzle alone. If you want to access member-specific information, you _could_ just use Guzzle, although some libraries provide a wrapper around the oauth transactions. To better understand the OAuth standard, I would recommend that you try to make a couple of authentications manually, and then move on to some wrapper libraries. That'll give you a better understanding of what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: But with the example in the post which this is a comment to, you should be fine with just the plain Guzzle library; I'll post an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Guzzle and Laravel, as the comments stated, this would be a very simple example of how to achieve this (just put it in `routes.php`):

```
Route::get( '/', function ()
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client( ["base_uri" => "https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/"] );

    $response = $client->request( "GET", "Listings/123.json", ["headers" => ["Authorization" => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="YOUR-CONSUMER-KEY", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_signature="YOUR-CONSUMER-SECRET&"']] );

    return Response::json($response->getBody()->getContents());
} );
```

Comment: when I run this I get an error `Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found`. In my `composer.json` I am using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"`, is that the right version for this?

Comment: Try `GuzzleHttp\Client` instead.

Comment: Ah, the above example is with `"guzzle/guzzle": "^3.9"` (which is deprecated). I'm gonna grab some food, after that I'll rewrite the example.

Comment: I know get the error `Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\tmapi\app\Http\routes.php on line 26 and defined`. When I run the `curl` code you first commented it works fine. If it is easier for you to test, I can give you the consumer key and consumer secret. They are only for a sandbox app and not live keys so there is no harm and I can regenerate them later for security?

Comment: Thanks Dencker, if you find you need the consumer key and consumer secret to make things easier for you then let me know. Happy to pass them along as it is only for a sandbox app.

Comment: Hey @James, see my updated answer :) I think we're good without the key and secret.

Comment: Works perfectly! You're a life saver @Dencker. I'm new to using API's and this is just what I needed

Comment: Great to hear, @James! Happy Coding ;-)